# Moving git repos to another drive/OS

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I am switching to linux over the next few months. I currently have Windows 10 installed on drive 1 and Ubuntu installed on drive 2.

All of my repose are stored on drive 1 where I used them in Windows. But I would like to move them all over to my Ubuntu drive and use them from Linux without loosing my commits.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That should work fine. Are you having any issues? Just make sure to move the entire directory including any hidden directories.

Simply moving/copying the directories via regular networking/filesystem commands should work. You could archive them first (via zip, tar, etc., whatever you can un-archive on Linux) to make sure you are getting everything.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to do it haha. Do I just literally move the files over to the new drive? Like drag and drop? Or do I need to do something with git? Like init the new directory first, clone from the other dir?

Comment: @Steve Yup, literal copy/paste, but ***make sure*** you copy the `.git` folder with the files, which is in the projects' folders. Also watch out for problems with line endings. You'll probably want to run everything through `dos2unix` And kudos for getting off Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the following steps may help:

1. switch to you windows system and put an usb storage device on it.
2. copy you git repo folder to your usb storage device(ie, using your right click to copy or drag the folder to your usb storage device).
3. switch to your ubuntu system and copy the git repo folder to some place.

Hope it helps.